# sharing data between two jenkins plugin

Tags: java, jenkins-plugins

I am having a requirement where the output of one plugin is the input for another plugin. Please provide some examples how to share data between two jenkins plugins.

Comment: Please Explain what exactly you want, What are the Jenkins plugins you are working with?

Comment: I had written my own plugins. One plugin is build plugin and other is post build plugin. the output of buildplugin should be taken as input of postbuild plugin